# Devise Invitable - Show how many invite left

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I am able to show the number of invites an user gets with

```
<%= @user.invitation_limit %>
```

However, I'd like to show how many invites are left. Any help?

Comment: but invitation limit does show how many invites are left. Or am I missing something?

Comment: not. it shows how many invites an user is allowed to send.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. First, set up a has_many association between your `User` model and `:invitations`.

```
# User.rb
....
has_many :invitations, :class_name => self.to_s, :as => :invited_by
```

This will give you access to

```
@user.invitations
```

Then you simply perform the math to get the display you're looking for.

```
<%= @user.invitation_limit - @user.invitations.count %>
```

To be more elegant, it's probably a good idea to create a helper and get the logic out of the view.

```
def invitations_remaining
  invitation_limit - invitations.count
end
```

Then you can simply call

```
<%= @user.invitations_remaining %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worth nothing that I wrote that 'helper' out more as a model method, and not proper convention for a helper. Suppose as a helper it should be `def invitations_remaining(user) user.invitation_limit - user.invitations.count end.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and then figured it out...you need to ask for the current user. If you just ask for `@user` you will get the default configuration limit you set in the devise initializer.

So just use `<%= current_user.invitation_limit %>` in place of `<%= @user.invitation_limit %>`.

Hope that helps.